# htaccess deny all at root, allow access matching url after a rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to secure an application on a shared hosting where I can only write .htaccess files. Everything is in the public folder www.

I want to restrict access to only one subdirectory while forbidding access to all others. I also want the root url `http://<domain>/` to show the content of that allowed directory.

```
www/
├── ...
├── private/
├── public/ (I want to allow access to this one only)
└── .htaccess
```

So far, my `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [R]

Order allow,deny
Deny from all

<Files "/public/*">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

With this, if I go visit `http://<domain>/public` everything works fine. But if I go to `http://<domain>/` I get a 403 access denied.

How can I redirect the root URL to show the content of my public folder, while still denying access to everything else at the root?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [L,R]
RewriteRule !public - [R=403]
```

Comment: Thanks ! If I restrict the path based on the URL only, won't that still allow to do something like `/public/../private` and get inside the private directory?